# Background science officer possibly played by Brent Spiner?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

I remember an episode where there is a science division officer in the background in Ten Forward who seems to be played by Brent Spiner out of makeup - I thought it was The Game, but I can't find that part now.  Does anyone recall which episode this was (assuming it's actually him)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not going to be Spiner. Contractually, main cast stars aren't allowed to play uncredited extras.

Comment: Why do you think that is, Valorum?

Comment: @HamSandwich - Because actor's credits (and in some cases, even how much screen-time and how many lines they're guaranteed each episode) are very carefully negotiated according to SAG standards. If you let a main character be an extra it would make it very easy to (effectively) kill off someone's character without actually dropping them, just by making them a background extra in each episode.

Answer (score 1):

This guy behind Riker? This is the scene in *The Game* when Troi is eating ice cream. He definitely looks like Brent/Data, but I don't think it's him. His  hair is different.

[image]

Comment: The OP mentioned that the character was a science division officer, which means that they should be wearing a blue/teal-coloured uniform, like Beverly Crusher's. Also, even if that were the character the OP was thinking of, this answer is incomplete without an episode title.

Comment: Having checked, it looks like that image is from act one of "[The Game](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Game_(episode))," the episode mentioned in the question, but that ideally should've been specified in the answer rather than leaving it unstated.